# Group policy home page not changing

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

We've recently made a new homepage and want to point users to the new one. I went into the existing group policy under User Configuration > Windows Settings > Internet Explorer > URLs and changed the homepage to the new one. The policy is at the domain level, enforced, link enabled and applying to authenticated users. We've gpupdate /force 'd computers, restarted, nothing is changing. I've looked at the other settings for internet explorer and don't see anything that would conflict. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behavior behavior of policies under Windows Settings -> Internet Explorer is somewhat different. I guess these only affect default configuration, so if user already had home page configured they don't modify it.

There are new settings for IE that have standard GP behavior under

```
User Configuration ->   
   Administrative Templates ->  
      Windows Components ->  
         Internet Explorer
```

The setting you want is called `Disable changing home page settings`. Despite the name, you can set a home page URL in this setting, and it will be enforced for all affected users.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to close this question, it turned out there was another GP that had the homepage set and it was overriding the change on the one I made.